# Women giving birth to organic industrial machinery before they can become "parents"

Tags: story-identification

I read a short story many years ago about a woman who lived in a time where women gave birth to organic industrial equipment. From what I can remember, it was a story at the end of a book of short stories, I don't know who wrote it. I remember something about the woman being told that she had produced an exceptional sample which could be used as a "ship mind" or something like that. There was a guy who tried to poison her while pregnant and make her miscarry. There was a letter at the end of the story congratulating her on now being allowed to have children of her own. Something about "motherhood"?

Comment: I've read the story (I think.)  If it is the same one, then the women didn't progress from organic machinery to becoming mothers.  Any woman could produce the organic machinery just by having sex with a genetically modified male whose sperm was modified to make the machines.  A woman who wanted to become a mother had to study all kinds of things and pass an exam in order to get some kind of license to be allowed to have and raise a child.  The story centered around one woman who takes all the classes and passes the exams while her girlfriends all run around having sex and popping out machines.

Comment: Can't remember where I read it, but I'm sure I don't own a copy.

Comment: There was a question like this before.  Here's the answer to that earlier question: https://www.smashwords.com/extreader/read/243397/1/piecework  That is the one I remembered.  "Piece Work" by David Brin.  Previous question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41149/looking-for-a-sf-story-regarding-women-growing-things-in-their-wombs?rq=1

Comment: Close voters: consensus is that we only close story ID questions as duplicates if we have unambiguous acceptance on both questions. We don't have that from the OP here.

Answer (score 5):

This is Piecework by David Brin. She gives birth to a "starbrain" I believe, and gets her license to have children afterward.

Comment: For the record, I knew the answer as soon as I saw the question in the list, and typed it in before I read any comments here. I'm not a cheat though, so if anyone objects, I'll gladly delete this one.

Comment: No "starbrain" in "Piece work."