# Short scifi story where reproductive organs are converted to produce "materials", pregnant protagonist is "found fit" to be a mother

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story I think in an Isaac Asimov short story collection - not necessarily his.

It’s about a world where reproductive organs where converted to produce all kinds of materials.

The protagonist is pregnant and kept the option to give birth and nurse.

She studies something. 
In the end she gives birth to a starship main computer and receive a letter that gives her the happy news that she finished school and found fit to be a mother.

Comment: Hi there. That is some good info already; if you can, please take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in :)

Comment: Eeeeeeh... Just to clarify, when you say _"she gives birth to a starship main computer"_, she programmed it or something, right? She did not _literally_ give birth to a computer? (I guess not, given the letter she receives, but still)

Comment: @Jenayah No, she literally gave birth to a gene-engineered construct designed to pilot a space ship.

Comment: @DavidW oof, delivery must've been something

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is most likely ["Piecework" by David Brin.](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/990794.Piecework)

[It is also the (unaccepted) answer to this other question.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108515/women-giving-birth-to-organic-industrial-machinery-before-they-can-become-paren?rq=1)

Women "produce" (give birth to) industrial equipment after having sex with men who have been genetically modified.

The story follows one woman who forgoes fast money.  Instead, she studies hard to earn a license to produce the most valuable "product" of all: a human child.

She has to study hard over months or years and pass examinations to earn a license to be allowed to become pregnant and have a child.

---

I do not know where you and the person who asked the other question get the idea of a star ship brain being involved.  This **is** the correct story, but you have that one detail wrong

Comment: Actually, her last (paid "egg-work") birth _was_ a ship brain, possibly a star brain.  You are mistaken on that point.

Comment: Accepted. JRE - I think there are two version to the story - one is the short version and then it was extended.

Comment: You people are awesome - tnx!

Comment: I too have that story, and it did refer to a "star brain". I also found it on Google Books: https://books.google.it/books?id=sB8PRnzQ5uAC&lpg=PT92&dq=parapyridine&hl=it&pg=PT92#v=onepage&q=starbrain&f=false